# I want to pass Main application view a model using backbone

Tags: backbone.js

```
define(['jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'app/js/components/models/Application'
], function($, _, Backbone , Application) {

var applicationView = Backbone.View.extend({

        model : new Application(),

        'initialize': function() {

            console.log('initializing app view...')

            this.render();
        },

        render: function() {

        }
    });
    return applicationView;
});
```

But it is showing me error as Uncaught TypeError: Application is not a function.

Application.js

```
define(['jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function($, _, Backbone) {

    var Application = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults : {
            version : 0.1
        },
        initialize : function(){

        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You application module doesn't return (*export*) anything, or to be technically correct, it returns (*exports*) `undefined`.

You should return your `Application` model constructor:

```
define(['jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone'
], function($, _, Backbone) {
  var Application = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        version : 0.1
    },
    initialize : function(){

    }
  });
 return Application; // <---------- add this
});
```

Also make sure `'app/js/components/models/Application'` is the correct path and you don't have other errors in console.